# How to add secured administrative endpoints to Spring OAuth2 Server?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

We are developing an Auth Server based on Spring Oauth2. We have managed to add custom data,  via custom `UserDetails` implementation (and some other custom components), to the tokens so that we can map Users in the Auth server to Entities in the application.

The application backoffice will also support the creation of new users through an administrative interface. For this reason we have opened some endpoints starting at `/users`.

We want this ednpoints to be only accessible to authenticated clients that have a trust scope. So requests to these endpoints are expected to supply an `Authorization` header with a valid `Bearer` token obtained via a Client Credentials Grant.

We have tried configuring the security of these endpoints extending the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Here are different versions of the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method and the outcomes:

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll();
```

This one works! But is not secured.

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated();
```

Fails!. It seems that the filter that does the authentication is not applied and I get a `403 Forbidden` response. The same happens substituting `authenticated()` with `hasRole(...)` or `hasAuthority(...)` or any other configuration that suggests an authenticated client.

The question is how can I configure the endpoint to secure it for clients with trusted scope?

Comment: You can use such expression: "#oauth2.hasScope('TRUSTED_SCOPE')"

Comment: It is code we do not manage. It is a Spring Oauth endpoint so we can not add security annotations.

Comment: I am facing similar issue.